# Refresh the content without page refresh

Tags: node.js, socket.io

hello i have developed the chat application using socket.io, expressjs and mongoose it works fine. it refreshes after some seconds and fetches new clients from db if exist. problem is that user can feel that div is refreshsing.and also some time take soem time in response. how to avoid this case. here is my code
  **This is my server side code**

```
  setInterval(function () {
  var allOnLine;
  allOnLine = io.sockets.clients();
   for (var client in allOnLine) {
    if (allOnLine[client].username == "undefined") {
    continue;
    } else {
    notifyAll(allOnLine[client].username);
    }
 }
 }, 50000);
```

and here is notify all method

```
function notifyAll(userName) {
      contactModel.find({'userId':userName}, (function (err, contactModel) {
         usernames = [];
         var contacts = contactModel;
         for (var a = 0; a < contacts.length; a++) {
            usernames[a] = contacts[a].contactId;
         }
         var allOnLine;
        allOnLine = io.sockets.clients();
        for (var client in allOnLine) {
            if (allOnLine[client].username == "undefined") {
                continue;
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
                    if (allOnLine[client].username == usernames[i]) {
                        usernames[i] = usernames[i] + " -On";
                    }

        allOnLine[client].username);
                }

            }
        }
        io.sockets.to(userName).emit('updateusers', usernames);

        }));
    }
```

**This is my client code**

```
socket.on('updateusers', function(usernames) {
     jQuery('#usernames').html('');
     jQuery.each(usernames, function(key, value) {
        jQuery('#usernames').append('<div class="chatContact" id="chatLink" onclick="privateChat(\''+value+'\')">' );
}}
```

any help i had also posted this question but no answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refresh the content without page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338544/refresh-the-content-without-page-refresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that youdelete everything from usernames and after that you write all contacts. You would better remove the offline contacts from the $('#usernames') and after that to add to that list the online contacts. I writed some functions to show you the functionality. I created html list of online contacts and I also created an array of new online contacts. Here is the code:

```
<div id="u">
  <div class="d" onclick="chat('asd1')">asd1</div>
  <div class="d" onclick="chat('asd12')">asd12</div>
  <div class="d" onclick="chat('asd13')">asd13</div>
  <div class="d" onclick="chat('asd142')">asd14</div>
</div>
```

Here you have the javascript that you need to run after the DOM is ready:

```
var onlineUsernames = ["asd211","asd12","asd13","asd14"];
var usernamesContainerID = 'u';
var $usernamesContainer = $('#'+usernamesContainerID);
function extractUsernameFromAttr(onclickValue)
{
  return onclickValue.split("'")[1];
}
function buildExistingUsernames($userDivs)
{
    var existingUsernames = [];
  $userDivs.each(function(index,value){
    var username = extractUsernameFromAttr($userDivs[index].getAttribute('onclick'));
    existingUsernames.push(username);
  })
  return existingUsernames;
}
function removeUserFromList($user)
{
     document.getElementById(usernamesContainerID).removeChild($user);
}
function addUserToList(value)
{
    $('<div/>',{
         onclick:"chat('"+value+"')",
         class :'d',
         text:value
   }).appendTo($usernamesContainer); 
}

function deleteOfflineContacts(existingUsernames,usernames,$userDivs)
{
  $.each(existingUsernames,function(index,value)
  {
     if($.inArray(value,usernames)==-1)
     {
        removeUserFromList($userDivs[index]);
     }       
  })
}
function addOnlineContacts(existingUsernames,usernames)
{
 $.each(usernames,function(index,value)
  {
     if($.inArray(value,existingUsernames)==-1)
     {
        addUserToList(value);
     }         
  })

}
function update($userDivs)
{
  var existingUsernames = buildExistingUsernames($userDivs);
  deleteOfflineContacts(existingUsernames,onlineUsernames,$userDivs);
  addOnlineContacts(existingUsernames,onlineUsernames);  
}
var $userDivs = $usernamesContainer.children("div");
setTimeout(function()
{
   update($userDivs);
},3000);
```

If you need it here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9gRyQ/2/

Comment: i cant remove offline contacts because my list shows all friends for the oter like facebook.

Comment: ok simply use just : addOnlineContacts(existingUsernames,onlineUsernames);

Comment: can you please simplify the addOnline Method im unable to get the logic :(

Comment: with the method $.each: I am iterating through all usernames and for each username I am checking if it exists in the list of already added users, I add a new user just if it is not exist. $.inArray checks if a certain value exists in an array. If it does not exist it returns -1